# What's the most efficient way to combine two Tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task

I have two `Task` objects I would like to run sequentially. Currently, my code to run them looks like this:

```
private async Task Advance(IToken token, SyntaxKind kind)
{
    await Approach(token);
    await Surpass(token, kind);
}
```

My question is, is this the most efficient way to combine them? I am aware that `async` involves a lot of state machine logic, so would it be more efficient to use `ContinueWith`?

```
private Task Advance(IToken token, SyntaxKind kind)
{
    // TODO: This would take advantage of the overload accepting a state
    // parameter to avoid the closure allocation
    return Approach(token).ContinueWith(() => Surpass(token, kind));
}
```

Please feel free to point out an alternative method (neither `await` nor `ContinueWith`) if you think it would be more efficient. Thank you.

**note:** For my case I am seeking the best way to combine two non-generic (resultless) `Task`s, but for the sake of people who come across this question by Google it's OK to include how to combine two `Task<TResult>`s in your answer, too.

Comment: Your code already runs `Approach` and `Surpass` sequentially. What's wrong with what you have? What do you mean "combine them"?

Comment: You've written the code both ways. You have some idea in your mind of what "efficiency" means. So: run the code both ways, measure its efficiency both ways, and then you will know which one is "more efficient". Use science; make some measurements. If you don't know how to measure "efficiency" then who cares which is more efficient? You can't tell.

Comment: If you care about optimization but not about saving Contexts between threads, why don't U use await "await Approach(token).ConfigureAwait(false); await Surpass(token, kind).ConfigureAwait(false);" ?

Answer (score 8):

> My question is, is this the most efficient way to combine them? I am aware that async involves a lot of state machine logic, so would it be more efficient to use ContinueWith?

The state machine logic is so trivial as to be immaterial in the face of any truly asynchronous operation (e.g., I/O). It's true that there is some overhead, but that's the price you pay for abstraction. I'm going to bet that the overhead will not be noticeable (or even measurable) unless you're calling this method in a tight loop and most of the operations complete synchronously.

If by "more efficient", you mean the method will run a few nanoseconds faster (more efficient for the CPU), then yes, `ContinueWith` is a tiny bit more efficient than `await`.

If by "more efficient", you mean that the code is more maintainable (more efficient for humans), then no, [`ContinueWith` is much less efficient than `await`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). It has the [same problems that `StartNew` does](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Your own example is an illustration of this: it's using the current `TaskScheduer` instead of the thread pool one, and it is not using the most appropriate flags.

If you want to dive deeper into the performance aspects of `await`, I recommend watching the [Zen of Async](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T) and reading [Understanding the Costs of Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx). However, I must caution all readers not to get caught up in micro-optimizations at the expense of maintainable code.

Comment: The "Zen of async" video link is not working, but someone has reposted that talk on youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjLWWz2YnyQ highly recommended for anyone working with `async`

Answer (score 2):

A way to optimize execution would be to specify [`TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). This would cause the continuation to be executed synchronously on the same thread that causes the antecedent task to transition into its final state. Consequently, you avoid the overheads associated with queuing the continuation onto the task scheduler and having it retrieved by a worker thread.

```
private Task Advance(IToken token, SyntaxKind kind)
{
    // TODO: This would take advantage of the overload accepting a state
    // parameter to avoid the closure allocation
    return Approach(token).ContinueWith(() => Surpass(token, kind), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}
```

If you're curious as to why this isn't done by default, see [Why is TaskContinuationsOptions.ExecuteSynchronously opt-in?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/05/24/why-is-taskcontinuationsoptions-executesynchronously-opt-in/)

Comment: ExecuteSynchronously **does not** guarantee anything. It is merely a request to scheduler.

Comment: @TanveerBadar: ...which is honored in the vast majority of cases.